# How to put text dynamically

Tags: android

I am new to the android development , so please pardon me if this is stupid question.
My question is "I have a pop-icon created in XML, representing kilometers like 3km,5km,10km....so on.I want call an activity which will find restaurants within that area( when user clicks 10 km btn then application should list all the restaurants within 10 km.And restaurants tag should have distance in kilometers on the pop-icon text. But I want to do this through java dynamically.

Please reply..

Answer (score 1):

If your class is an subclass of [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html), you can use [setText](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText%28java.lang.CharSequence,android.widget.TextView.BufferType%29).

In general case, search for a setText method in the documentation of the class you are using.